# set popup while theme my login plugin register form submit

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am working with theme my login plugin in wordpress. I have created popup after theme my login register. I have written jquery to display popup when register form is submit.The code is like :

```
$('#registerform').submit(function(){
    var mob = $("#cimy_uef_1").val();
    var email = $("#user_email").val();
    var pass1 = $("#pass1").val();
    var pass2 = $("#pass2").val();

    var len = $(".tml-register").find(".error").length;

    if(email != '' && pass1 != '' && pass2 != '' && pass1 == pass2)
    {
        //alert("nisarg");
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo plugins_url()."/invoice-system/send_sms.php"; ?>",         
            data: {mob:mob,email:email},            
        }).done(function(html){
            $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');

            //close popup
            $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
                if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
                }
            });
            //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.which=='27'){
                    $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
                }
            });},10000);

        });
    }
```

Here the form is also submitted. When I submit form then page is reload so my popup is display for few seconds. Here I want to display popup after registration till I close popup. So what should I have to do?

Comment: You may use AJAX for the registration/login part if you want the popup to stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to stop form from submitting, you can do that using:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Then you need to resubmit the form on popup close. You can do that using:

```
$( "#registerform" ).submit();
```

Your complete code will look like this:

```js
$('#registerform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mob = $("#cimy_uef_1").val();
    var email = $("#user_email").val();
    var pass1 = $("#pass1").val();
    var pass2 = $("#pass2").val();

    var len = $(".tml-register").find(".error").length;

    if(email != '' && pass1 != '' && pass2 != '' && pass1 == pass2)
    {
        //alert("nisarg");
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo plugins_url()."/invoice-system/send_sms.php"; ?>",         
            data: {mob:mob,email:email},            
        }).done(function(html){
            $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');

            //close popup
            $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
                $( "#registerform" ).submit();
                if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
                }
            });
            //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.which=='27'){
                    $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
                }
            });},10000);

        });
    }
```

Comment: It works but form data is not submitted. I can not insert data into table.